# Past perfect or simple with time duration

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

1a) He was craving pizza because he didn't have it for months.

1b) He was craving pizza because he hadn't had it for months.

2a) he smelled so bad because he didn't have shower for 10 days.

2b) he smelled so bad because he hadn't had shower for 10 days.

What's the difference here and what's correct?

Comment: Both situations are the result of past circumstances, so I would use the 'b' version for both (and it's 'have **a** shower').

Comment: What's the difference if we use "a" can we use it interchangeably?

Comment: To me as a British English speaker, "He didn't have pizza for months" is just a statement, which could be followed by "...and by January he was really craving some". Your sentences  refer to the time when he was already craving pizza/smelling bad, so what caused those states is in the past. (As I mentioned in response to an earlier question of yours, American usage may differ.)

Comment: Oh, so I can use past perfect it won't be considered wrong or Fromal in these sentences right?

Comment: I've already told you that I would use the past perfect in both cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found out and discovered with past simple or perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330330/found-out-and-discovered-with-past-simple-or-perfect)

Comment: @KateBunting That's an answer, not a comment.