# didn't notice with past simple or perfect

Tags: past-tense

I didn't notice he fell.
I didn't notice he'd fallen.

I didn't notice he stole my money.
I didn't notice he'd stolen my money.

what's the difference and what's more correct?

Comment: no i don't know whats correct

Comment: In relaxed conversation, we sometimes use Simple Past in such contexts, but strictly speaking it should nearly always be Past Perfect. But normally ***not*** in a context like *I didn't realise he **had** liked ice-cream*, though.

Comment: in my examples both think happend first and I didn't notice so what is natural here?

Comment: more example ; i was sneaking into his house and i didn't know he saw me or had seen me

Comment: Native speakers don't believe in right and wrong in most of these cases. They simply say whatever they feel like saying. Please read the "Related" questions.

Comment: yes i know just tell my that if they are both correct or i should use past perfect here  "i was sneaking into his house and i didn't know he saw me or had seen me"

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions about the differences between simple and perfect verb forms: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330330/found-out-and-discovered-with-past-simple-or-perfect, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330767/did-or-had-done, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330522/past-perfect-or-simple-with-time-duration, etc. If people aren't answering your questions sufficiently, then you should follow up on those questions instead of constantly posting new questions on the same topic.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I am walking with my friend on a narrow track. I am in the lead, and my friend, who is behind me, falls over.

"**I didn't notice he fell**" could mean that I wasn't looking at him at the moment he fell. You could make that idea clearer by saying "I didn't notice him falling", but "I didn't notice (that) he fell" is not wrong.

"**I didn't notice he'd fallen**" would suggest that the falling happened earlier than the non-noticing. (He fell over, and several minutes later I was still walking on ahead, unaware.) It might also suggest the idea of falling and staying fallen. (For example, if he fell and hurt his leg, so he couldn't get up.)

So there's no completely right answer here, because it depends what you are trying to say. This is often true when using English tenses in combination. It's not about learning what's right or wrong. It's about learning how to put them together to communicate your ideas correctly.

Comment: What a wonderful answer!

Comment: that really helped me. but with "I didn't know" I am still confused If we apply same sentence but with I didn't know so what is the difference then? 




"I didn't know he fell "I didn't know he'd fallen" and "I didn't know he stole your money l" I didn't know he'd stolen your money.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your original question used the word "notice". Are we now asking a different question?

Comment: I suggest you use my answer to construct one sentence of your own, and tell us what you think it means. Practise interpreting different tenses :)